# React app Yarn errors

Tags: react.js

I am following a React tutorial. I created a React app in Visual Code Studio using np create-react-app. I then entered yarn start. I got the following error,
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve. These are some of the errors listed in the index.js file (the file path is inventory\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js).

```
    import { formatProblem, createOverlay } from "./overlay.js";
import { log, logEnabledFeatures, setLogLevel } from "./utils/log.js";
import sendMessage from "./utils/sendMessage.js";
import reloadApp from "./utils/reloadApp.js";
import createSocketURL from "./utils/createSocketURL.js";

/**
 * @typedef {Object} OverlayOptions
 * @property {boolean | (error: Error) => boolean} [warnings]
 * @property {boolean | (error: Error) => boolean} [errors]
 * @property {boolean | (error: Error) => boolean} [runtimeErrors]
```